# Invoke RestMethod issues parsing JSON: Value not convertible to Int

Tags: json, rest, powershell, websense

I have to use PowerShell to manage a Websense server via API.  I am using Invoke-RestMethod and I am using a json format to make the changes.  The comand to the server is as follows:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriCreate -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body ($jsonCat | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
```

My variables are as follows:

```
$uriCreate = https://<ipaddress>:<port>/api/web/v1/categories
$headers = @{ Authorization = <credentials> }
$jsonCat = [ordered]@{
    "Transaction ID" = $transID
    Categories = @(
        [ordered]@{
            "Category Name" = $catName
            "Category Description" = $catDesc
            "Parent" = $catID
          }   
        )
    }
```

When I attempt to create the category via Powershell I get the following error returned:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
   "Error" : [ "Could not parse JSON: Value is not convertible to Int." ]
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: ArSounds like a property that needs needs to be a Int isnt a Int. Could be a $null or something else?

Comment: What about casting `$transID` and/or `$catID` to an `[int]$transID` resp. `[int]$catID` ?

Comment: @LotPings that appears to have been the issue.  I am surprised, because I figured that the ConvertTo-Json function would have rendered that unnecessary but I guess that teaches me not to take anything for granted.